# Kotlin Reflection как проверить класс обобщенного типа

Tags: generics, рефлексия, kotlin

В kotlin пытаюсь использовать рефлекшн. Столкнулся со следубщим поведением (Скриншоты из дебаггера)

Сначала я вывожу тайп поля 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Его тип RealmList, делаю проверку без обобщения, получаю ошибку и совет использовать * как маску

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Делаю это и получаю в результате, что условие field.type (Как мы помним RealmList) == RealmList<*> = false

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно изменить условие проверки, чтобы получить true?

Answer (score 0):

Получил true таким образом:

```
field.type.javaClass.isInstance(RealmList<T>().javaClass
```

но выглядит это крайне ужасно. Может есть более простой способ? :)

Comment: RealmList это у вас класс Java или класс Kotlin? Вообще, у них в доке очень подробно все описано https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html  Вы что конкретно сделать хотите

Comment: @rjhdby realmlist это java класс. В данном случае мне нужно проверить тип